# Ideal gear ratio for pulling mass up a slope with highest final velocity

Tags: energy-conservation, velocity, torque

For a engineering project we are trying to create a mechanism to launch a plane. In order to do this, we hang a mass *m1* on a drum moves downwards and spins a gear system with gear ratio *i* (I am aware that the gears in the picture would lower the mass *m2* not pull it up, imagine a middle gear to solve this in the picture). This pulls in a mass *m2* for a maximum distance *d* on a slope with angle *a*. The variables *m1*, *m2*, *d* and *a* area all known. You can assume no friction is present in any of the components. Not sure if it is relevant, but *m1* > *m2*.

What is the optimal gear ratio to maximize the velocity *m2* has when it reaches the end of the slope (after traveling distance *d*)?
[image]

An updated picture of this problem:
[image]

A picture of the work I did assuming the gears are a simple pulley:
[image]

Comment: They way you've got it set up, $m_2$ will move *down* the slope, not up!

Comment: Considering this is your project to do, why are you outsourcing the thinking to us? What are your thoughts on the issue at hand and what have you tried?

Comment: @Gert I am aware of this, as I mentioned, just imagine a gear in the middle to fix that, when I created the image I forgot to add that

Comment: @Triatticus We have tried some things using a force balance and torque, energy balance and trying to solve for v, but we are all not very skilled at this and so far only had some minor ideas on how to do it, but not really anything rigorous

Comment: You should try putting work you've done and calculations you've tried in the post, it will better help people understand what your specific issue might be. For instance you know how to do the force analysis here if that set of gears were a pully right?

Comment: @Triatticus Yes, I've added a picture showing the equations I worked out in that case.

Comment: Well then you will have to determine the angular acceleration of the 'pully' as a function of the gear ratio then and optimize that.

Comment: The program WinTreb, or its ilk may be instructive...

Comment: @DJohnM We are explicitly not allowed to use a trebuchet like mechanism.

Comment: @Triatticus That's the part where I got stuck at, could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like energy considerations are a very good way of solving this. I assume you know the principle of equating potential energy lost with kinetic energy gained.
Incidentally I don’t know why you don’t just use connected reels of different diameters on the same shaft rather than gears.
[image: Reel]

$√(2gh)$ is the velocity of a free object after falling a height of h

You can fiddle with the parameters to get the greatest velocity (multiply by $k$ to get the final velocity of the plane). If you are ambitious and you know calculus then you can differentiate the plane velocity function wrt k to find the maximum.

Note that it is quite easy to add friction into the energy calculation. It is not quite so easy to add the rotational kinetic energy of the reel – just make it light.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that's what I'm looking for! When working on the energy approach to this problem I added the factor k to both masses, your approach makes a lot more sense ;). I assume that in the case of reels connected to the same axle you can simple take *k* as the ratio between diameters of the reels right? The initial design was sketched in 3D, after that I did not consider using the extra dimension to my advantage, hence the gears. It would be a good idea to look into having the reels on the same axle, thanks for the suggestion.